# Find repeating field value count in MySQL table

Tags: jquery, mysql, sql

Have following `games` table

```
  `id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `content` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci,
  `team1ID` int(7) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `team2ID` int(7) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `championshipID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `date` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Event_team1ID_Team_id` FOREIGN KEY (`team1ID`) REFERENCES `Team` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `FK_Event_team2ID_Team_id` FOREIGN KEY (`team2ID`) REFERENCES `Team` (`id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

What I need is to get list of team names from `team` table ordered by game count (count of games left).  All details about games located in `games` table

I will describe conditions:

- with `games.championshipID=1`
- list must be ordered descending (from maximum game count to minimum)
- Game count must be calculated in `games` table by searching for `games.team1ID, games.team2ID`
- and `games.date` > current timestamp

Well result must look like that

```
 team name | games left
   teamWithId5  | 68 (row count from games table)
   teamWithId250| 50 
   teamWithId250 | 4
```

Can't figure out how sql query must look like. Any suggestions?

Thx in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
select concat('teamwithid', temp_table.id), count(*) as games
from
(
select teamid1 as id from games where games.date>curdate()
union all
select teamid2 from games games.date>curdate()
) as temp_table
group by 1 order by 2 desc
```

Comment: forgot the from, try now

Answer (score 0):

```
select t.Name,
       count(*) as gameCount
from   (select team1ID as id
        from   games
        where  championshipId = 1 and
               date > now()
        union all
        select team2ID as id
        from   games
        where  championshipId = 1 and
               date > now()) allGames 
        join team t on allGames.id = t.Id
group by t.Name
order by gameCount desc
```

Comment: it returned empty table as result

Comment: just try running the subquery - if no data comes back then it's because of all game dates being in the past, or no games with championshipId = 1